# Two lists of same objects have different hash codes

Tags: java, list, hash, hashmap, hashcode

I have a question regarding the hashCode implementation of an List in java.

For better understanding, I will simply describe my data construct.
I read graph information from two different databases and store it in a abstract graph representation. Therefore I have two HashMaps, one for each database. The map contains a `String` as Key and a `GraphLayer` object as value: `HashMap<String, GraphLayer>`. The GraphLayer object has two custom members of type `PaperMetaData` and `ConferenceSerieAndInstance`. `PaperMetaData` consists of some members of primitive `String` type and an member of `HashMap<Author, Set<Affiliation>>`. The Author contains just primitive String members, as well as Affiliation. `ConferenceSerieAndInstance` contains also normal String members and a member of type `HashMap<String, ConferenceInstance>`, where the class ConferenceInstance just conatins String members. 
I hope, so far everything is clear.

I read out my information from each database and store it in each HashMap for the database. Afterwards I convert each map in a list. So far so good, but the order of the objects in the list is different (as well as in the Map before I convert the map). The cast from HashMap to ArrayList looks like this.

```
public List<GraphLayer> searchAuthor() { 
    ...
    return (List<GraphLayer>) new ArrayList<GraphLayer>(graph.values());
}
```

But both lists contains the same objects. If I call the Method `hashCode()` of each list, I get different hash codes.

I don't understand why I get different hash codes. According to the java documentation, the hash code of a list will be created like that.

```
  int hashCode = 1;
  for (E e : list)
      hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
```

So the order of the items in the list should not play a role. If I try it with a list with primitive datatypes, like String, it will work, but not with my custom datatype.

Does anyone has an idea why it does not work?

I compared also each hash code of the members of the `PaperMetaData` and `ConferenceSerieAndInstance` in list one, with the hash code of the members in list two. And there is no difference. But if I compare the hashcode of the complete list, there is a difference. I have no idea why. I'm helpless.

Perhaps somebody can help me out. Best regards and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Your answer lays here

> So far so good, but the order of the objects in the list is different
>   (as well as in the Map before I convert the map).

### [`List#equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

> [...] two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in
>   the same order

---

### EDIT By @SamiKuhmonen

And to elaborate: the hashcode calculation has a loop with summing and multiplying. If hashcodes are 1 and 2 and on another list 2 and 1, the results are 1*31+2 and 2*31+1, so it's clear that they are not the same.

---

### Example

```
List<String> one = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> two = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> three = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] s = "A B C".split(" ");

for (String a : s){
    one.add(a);
    two.add(a);
}

for (int i = s.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
    three.add(s[i]);
}

System.out.println(one.hashCode());     // 94369
System.out.println(two.hashCode());     // 94369
System.out.println(three.hashCode());   // 96289
System.out.println(one.equals(two));    // true
System.out.println(two.equals(three));  // false
```

Comment: And to elaborate: the hashcode calculation has a loop with summing and multiplying. If hashcodes are 1 and 2 and on another list 2 and 1, the results are 1*31+2 and 2*31+1, so it's clear that they are not the same.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Nice, I'm adding this and quoting you. Thanks.